# If you see this name how do you pronounce it?

Tags: names

My name is Tomas without the "H" (Thomas)

**If you see this name how do you pronounce it ??**

Thank you

Comment: I am afraid there are few topics that are more dialect and opinion based then the pronunciation of names.

Comment: The English name 'Thomas' is generally pronounced quite differently by people in the US and people in the UK. I'd have guessed, without context,  that 'Tomas' was more probably a transliteration from an Eastern European variant.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth   Only the O is different. Really. And Tomas would be pronounced by reader interpretation. If I knew the person was Spanish, I would shift the tonic accent to the second syllable. Otherwise, I would pronounce Tomas like Thomas (the o difference not being relevant to that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pronunciation question, not a language usage question.

Answer (score 3):

"Tomas" when written in English is generally assumed to be the Spanish name (at least in my experience in the United States).  Which is indeed pronounced "to-MAS"; the correct spelling in Spanish has an accent, Tomás, but it is often dropped in the US.

Comment: I concur with John Feltz: Tomas would be /Toh-MAHS/; Thomas is /TAHM-us/.